# For/if state works one way, but not the other

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements, string-comparison, with-statement

I typically hate asking for help but I've beat myself up enough over this.

When I do the following the function works and gives the desired output (matching lines between files). If I reverse the files the for/if statement is using, I do not get the lines that match up between the files. So, it is pulling the desired (same) text from both files one way but not the other.

Works:

```
 with open('textfile1.txt','r') as t1, open('textfile2.txt', 'r') as t2:
     for line in t1:
         if line in t2:
             print(line)
```

Does not work:

```
 with open('textfile1.txt','r') as t1, open('textfile2.txt', 'r') as t2:
      for line in t2:
         if line in t1:
            print(line)
```

I'm sure this is something simple, but I have literally stared at this for longer than I care to say. This is a very small piece of code I'm trying to get to work for a much bigger project I'm working on. I just can't seem to get this specific issue resolved.

**Solution**:

```
 with open('textfile1.txt','r') as t1, open('textfile2.txt', 'r') as t2:
      t1_lines = set(t1)  
      for line in t2:
         if line in t1_lines:
            print(line)
```

Comment: error message is?

Comment: There is no error message. That's the thing. If I had some kind of error code I would understand. It's just one way works and the other flat out doesn't.. It's very confusing.

Comment: Using set fixed my issue!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `in` on a file and have it work twice.

What happens is that `in` *moves the file reader position forward*. A file object is an *iterable* and `in` on such an object takes each object (lines from the file in this case) to test if one is equal. When you find an equal object, iteration stops and `True` is returned. If no equal object is found iteration continues until you reach the end.

For example, if `t2` contains just *one extra line*, then trying to find that line in `t1` will cause all of `t1` to be read to try to find it. Any subsequent line read from `t2` will now fail, because `t1` has reached the end and no more lines will be returned.

At no point in this process will the iterable be 'rewound' to the start. The file read pointer only moves forward, never back to the start.

If using `in` worked in one scenario, then that means that each line read from `t1` also happens to be present *in the same order* in `t2`. The reverse is not true, if `t2` contains *extra lines* that are present in a different order in the first file.

If your files are small, reach one of the files into a *set object*:

```
with open('textfile1.txt','r') as t1, open('textfile2.txt', 'r') as t2:
    t1_lines = set(t1)
    for line in t2:
         if line in t1_lines:
             print(line)
```

A set lets you test for the presence of an object in *constant time*; regardless of how many lines there are in `t1`, on average it'll always take the same amount of time to test for one of those lines.

If you work with *large* files, you could force the file pointer back to the start, by using `fileobj.seek(0)`. However, reading across files (each line is reach when scanning for an `in` test) is going to be *slow*. You could use [memory mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html) to mitigate this a little, but you probably would want to ensure your file lines were sorted and then use an index or bisection to speed up the process of finding a matching line.

Comment: The first text file is a report with roughly 1,000 lines give or take some. The second is a list of striped out findings that are in order of how they would appear in the overall report. 

Why would the for loop not go down the report and check if that line is in the striped file? It should get each line, check if that line is in the other file, if it is, print it.

Comment: @kizzzzurt: because each `in` test moves the file pointer **forward**, never back. If the first test finds a line halfway down into the file, the second test will search for a match **from that point forward**, so searching the second half of the file. If a match is found, the pointer stops there and the next search continues from there. If no match is found, **you reached the end of the file**.

Answer (score 3):

Iterators are exhausted after one pass. `t1` and `t2` are iterators. They yield one line of the file with each iteration.

`if line in t2` iterates through `t2` until a match is found. If no match is found, `t2` will be completedly exhausted. So the next time `if line in t2` is tested, no match will be found even if `line` is in `textfile2.txt`.

---

For example, suppose `textfile1.txt` contains

```
BAR
BAZ
```

and `textfile2.txt` contains

```
FOO
BAR
```

Then consider

```
with open('textfile1.txt','r') as t1, open('textfile2.txt', 'r') as t2:
     for line in t2:
        if line in t1:
           print(line)
```

On the first pass through the loop, `line` is `'FOO'` (let's ignore the end of line character here). `if line in t1` causes `t1` to iterate through `BAR` and `BAZ`. Since `line` is not equal to either of these, `t1` is exhausted and the loop goes on to the next value.

On the second pass, `line` equals  `BAR`. Now `if line in t1` tests if `BAR` is in an empty iterator. So no line ever gets printed.

---

In contrast, when running

```
with open('textfile1.txt','r') as t1, open('textfile2.txt', 'r') as t2:
    for line in t1:
        if line in t2:
            print(line)
```

On the first pass through the loop, `line` is `BAR`. Now `if line in t2` is True since `t2` will yield the line `BAR`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the answer. If I flip flop between the two files, one works and the other doesn't.

Would it matter if the files of significantly different lengths for any reason?

Comment: @kizzzzurt: of course this is the answer. If one file contains just *one line extra*, then it'll work in one direction, but not the other. If `t1` contains `foo`, `bar` and `ham`, and `t2` contains `foo`, `spam`, `bar` and `ham`, then your test works in one direction but not the other. Because `spam` can't be found in `t1`, and the search for that line reads the whole file.